# Display street view of specific marker location

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How can I add street view of specific marker location `theStore` to the map on `#street` click event?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="street">Street View</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var theStore = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: theStore,
          map: map
        });

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(street, 'click', function () {
        //Display Street View of theStore
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set the position to the position of the certain marker:

```
panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setPosition(theStore);
panorama.setVisible(true);
```